# How can I write a query to get a view count in a specific time frame with no timestamp?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know how many times a page is viewed in a specific timeframe, say the last 30 days. In the database there is a PageViewCount field so every time the page is viewed, the PageViewCount increases, but there is no timestamp in the database of when this occurs.

I know there has to be a simple solution to this, but I am having a real hard time wrapping my brain around it.

Comment: I am sorry but lets assume page 'ABC' was viewed 10 times on 1 May, then 34 times on 9 May. You have one row 'ABC',44. The question is how to split this value for 1 May and 9 May ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated, it is impossible to query for such a value. Consider the following equivalent example: I have some coins, for a total of $3.50 and I don't track the movements of the coins. How much money did I had yesterday?

You should have a daily procedure that stores the current `PageViewCount` with the current date in another table and then simply query that table.

Comment: I figured this was the case but I wanted to make sure. Yes that would all have to be built in. Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.